# Missing feature in AWS CLI step

Tags: octopus-deploy

I'm using `Run an AWS CLI Script` with referenced package. But such step does not allow to add feature `.NET Configuration Variables`, however plain `RUN A SCRIPT` allows it. Could be I'm missing something, but is this possible to enable somehow that feature for `Run an AWS CLI Script`?